# Mock an ArrayObject with PHPUnit

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit, arrayobject

My problem is that I have to mock a class which extends \ArrayObject and I want to use this mocked object in a foreach, but I get this exception:

**Exception: Objects returned by Mock_ItemCollection_3ab4029b::getIterator() must be traversable or implement interface Iterator**

I've checked the manual and the actual types in code (with instanceof) and the object I get is Traversable (but not Iterator).

How can I solve this problem?
(BTW, the original class works great with foreach)

**Update:**
This is how I try to mock the class:

```
class ItemCollection extends \ArrayObject implements StatefulInterface, ItemCollectionInterface {...}

$mockIC = $this->getMockBuilder('\SK\API\Model\ItemCollection\ItemCollection')
            ->setConstructorArgs(array($this->container->get('mongo.db')))
            ->getMock();
```

Comment: could you show how do you mock this class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that phpunit will stub all methods from `ItemCollection` (because you didn't specify any of them). If you will specify at least one method (for example through `setMethods` method) then phpunit will stub only these specified methods and the rest of them will stay as in original class (for example `getIterator` method).

So, the question is - why do you need mock that class? If you want stub/mock just one method from it, then do it only for that one:

```
 $mockIC = $this->getMockBuilder('\SK\API\Model\ItemCollection\ItemCollection')
        ->setMethods(array('methodYouWantStub'))
        ->setConstructorArgs(array($this->container->get('mongo.db')))
        ->getMock();
```